# Compiling for old versions of Debian

Tags: debian, compiling

Can I build packages for Debian 5.0 using Debian 6.0 or Debian Wheezy?

I assume that I could do a complete chroot'ed installation of Debian 5.0 and do my builds there, but it might be nice to have something lighter-weight.

For bonus points - can I build packages for Debian 5.0 using the version of g++ from Debian 6.0 or Debian Wheezy?  I'm responsible for developing some Debian 5.0 software, but I'd like to start using C++11 features that aren't available in Debian 5.0's g++.

Comment: A chroot is exactly what Debian developers use in this circumstance. Debian comes with several tools to make this very easy.

Comment: Here is a patch for backporting 4.7 to stable. It isn't what you were asking, but will give you an idea what is involved. See [Get newest gcc for debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36388/get-newest-gcc-for-debian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the `schroot` or `pbuilder` packages convenient for this, since they are designed to maintain a build environment for multiple versions of Debian.

That said, a basic chroot is a couple of hundred MB in size; you could have thousands of them on most modern systems without really noticing.  `debootstrap` is a great tool for getting those working swiftly.

Building with a newer version of G++ is traditionally exciting, because the support libraries also need to change - and so the older glibc release may not support your newer binary code well.

You should be able to backport the appropriate version of G++ and have it work, but directly using the newer version might cause problems.  The release notes should help understand that.