# Install gcc 4.7.2 on Debian squeeze 64x

Tags: debian, software-installation, gcc

I want to use gcc 4.7.2 on my Debian squeeze 64x

I followed instructions in this thread: [Get newest gcc for debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36388/get-newest-gcc-for-debian), but I'm getting an error, I tried several apt-get install commands

I will settle with 4.7.1, as long as i can use the new c++ 11 features.

Below are my updated sources list and preferences file.
After i updated these files i used apt-get update from a root terminal.

**/etc/apt/sources.list**

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 _Squeeze_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20120512-20:40]/ squeeze main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 _Squeeze_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20120512-20:40]/ squeeze main

deb http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze main
deb-src http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze main

deb http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.belnet.be/debian/ squeeze-updates main

deb http://apt.jenslody.de/stable stable main
deb-src http://apt.jenslody.de/stable stable main
deb http://apt.wxwidgets.org/ squeeze-wx main
```

**/etc/apt/preferences**

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=squeeze
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release n=wheezy
Pin-Priority: 200
```

It seems that this helped but now apt-get is complaining about unmet dependencies

```
root@debianWillem:/home/willem# apt-get install gcc-4.7/testing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '4.7.1-7' (Debian:testing [amd64]) for 'gcc-4.7'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.7 : Depends: cpp-4.7 (= 4.7.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: binutils (>= 2.21.1) but 2.20.1-16 is to be installed
           Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.7.1-7) but 1:4.4.5-8 is to be installed
           Depends: libgomp1 (>= 4.7.1-7) but 4.4.5-8 is to be installed
           Depends: libmpfr4 (>= 3.1.0) but 3.0.0-2 is to be installed
           Recommends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-5) but 2.11.3-3 is to be installed
E: Broken packages

root@debianWillem:/home/willem# apt-get --target-release testing install gcc-4.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 initscripts : Breaks: console-setup (< 1.74) but 1.68+squeeze2 is to be installed
               Breaks: nfs-common (< 1:1.2.5-3) but 1:1.2.2-4squeeze2 is to be installed
 libglib2.0-0 : Breaks: eog (< 3.2.2-3) but 2.30.2-1 is to be installed
 libgnome-keyring0 : Breaks: gnome-keyring (< 3.0) but 2.30.3-5 is to be installed
 network-manager : Recommends: crda but it is not going to be installed
                   Breaks: network-manager-gnome (< 0.9) but 0.8.1-2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

How do i resolve these unmet dependencies ?

Comment: Could you post the `apt-get install` command you used please?

Comment: First, to confirm, you ran `apt-get update` first (after editing your `sources.list`), correct? Second, please post the two files you edited—`/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/preferences`.

Comment: @derobert i upated my question with the files, i forgot to run apt-get update, i updated my question, it seems like i'm almost there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gcc-4.7.2 was released 3 days ago on September 20th. <del>It won't have made it into the debian repos yet</del> (See update2, thanks derobert).

According to the [release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/) it is a bug-fixing release so will probably use the same library versions as the previous, 4.7.1, release. So, since 4.7.1 is in the repos, install it to get all the dependencies sorted, then if you *really really* need the latest version, download the source and compile following the instructions from the [gcc website](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/).

---

UPDATE:

You seem to have a problem with your source.lst. As a workaround, try downloading the package [here](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gcc) and installing using `dkpg -i gcc_4.7.1-1_amd64.deb`.

---

UPDATE 2:

As @derobert points out below, 4.7.2 is indeed in the experimental repo. So, adapt the instructions from the [post you linked to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36415/22222):

Your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should look something like this:

```
deb local.debian.mirror squeeze main
deb local.debian.mirror unstable main
```

while your `/etc/apt/preferences` should look something like this:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=squeeze
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release n=unstable
Pin-Priority: 200
```

Then install using `apt-get install gcc-4.7/unstable`.

As both jordanm and the original tutorial you linked to mention, this is not a very good idea. **Make sure to point your sources back to stable once you're finished.**

Comment: i updated my question, please take a look.

Comment: @helmus, that is strange. Please link to or post your `/etc/apt/sources.lst` file and also the output of this command: `sudo apt-get install gcc/testing`

Comment: FYI, 4.7.2 is in unstable.

Comment: That pinning will likely lead to broken system when he tries to install a package that doesn't exist in stable, it selects the sid version which pulls in sid's libc (just one scenario).

Comment: @jordanm so how do i fix that ?