# Can't update GCC version from 4.9.2 to 5.4 or 6.2?

Tags: debian, package-management, gcc

I am trying to update `gcc` version in debian pc, but no luck yet.

I have followed the instruction given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/507068/106854) and changed the last command to `apt-get install gcc-5.4 g++-5.4` but it seems no installable package is available for latest gcc verion. Even `aptitude search gcc-5` does not list anything.

**EDIT  :** Adding output of `cat /etc/*-release`

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/*-release`

Comment: @schaiba : I have added it's output in question.

Comment: Those instructions you are quoting are for Ubuntu. On Debian 8 gcc5 is not available. Please see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284817/how-to-install-gcc-5-on-debian-jessie-8-1 .

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of `gcc` can be installed from from testing on debian jessie using apt-pinning:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
touch testing.list
```

Add this `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free` to file `testing.list`

Now move into directory

`/etc/apt/preferences.d/`

And add this

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: 100
```

to newly created file `testing.list`.

```
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -t testing gcc
```

Note that using `-t testing` you tell `apt-get` to `install gcc` from testing sources as configured in above steps.