# how can I install gcc 4.8 or higher on wheezy?

Tags: debian, package-management, gcc

I want to compile a library that need gcc 4.8 or higher. how can I install it on wheezy (32bit)?

```
# apt-get install gcc-4.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-4.8
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-4.8'
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Have you seen e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89243/how-to-install-gcc-4-8-1-on-debian-wheezy

Answer (score 2):

You can't, at least not easily.

The [version of gcc shipped with wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/gcc) is 4.7.2. That means there is no (precompiled) gcc 4.8 available for Debian wheezy.

You *could* compile your own version of gcc and try to do it that way, but that's a lot of work and not at all guaranteed to work. It might be easier to just upgrade to Jessie instead, which comes with gcc 4.9.

Comment: It may be worth checking the wheezy-backports releases to see if it is there... However I recall something about the kernel series for Wheezy not being compatible with the latest gcc...

Comment: @ivanivan backports does not carry something as core and as crucial as gcc...