# Install gcc into x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: debian, gcc

I'm trying to compile and install gcc-4.9.0 on my Debian system, and in particular I want the new version to overwrite an old version of libstdc++.so.6 in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` that came as standard with my distribution, but which offends various other programs I've installed because it is too old.

When I built from source, the configure options I used (with guidance from [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/gcc.html)) were:

```
configure --prefix=/usr           \
          --libdir=/usr/lib       \
          --enable-shared         \
          --enable-threads=posix  \
          --enable-__cxa_atexit   \
          --enable-clocale=gnu    \
          --disable-multilib      \
          --with-system-zlib      \
          --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran
```

`make` and `make install` ran successfully; `make` puts the compiled code into `gcc-build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, but unexpectedly `make install` copies it not into `/usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu`, but into `/usr/lib64`.

What configuration option should I use to get the final version into `/usr/lib/x86_64-linuc-gnu`?

I thought that perhaps the problem was the `--disable-multilib` option, but when I tried to compile without this I got a configure error to the effect:

```
configure: error: I suspect your system does not have 32-bit developement    libraries (libc and headers). If you have them, rerun configure with --enable-multilib. If you do not have them, and want to build a 64-bit-only compiler, rerun configure with --disable-multilib.
```

...so it obviously isn't that.

Comment: What is "your system"? Please be specific? Debian wheezy? I've got instructions about backporting gcc 4.9 [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126616/4671) if you are interested. It did work for me.

Comment: Note that installing gcc 4.9 debs causes the `libgcc1` package to be upgraded from 4.7 to 4.9.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126433/4671

Comment: I'm on Wheezy, so your link does in fact look very relevant. I'll have a go at it, but probably not until Thursday.

Comment: Ok. Are you on amd64 or i386?

Comment: I'm on amd64, and only need to install the 64-bit version

Comment: If you need assistance, let me know. You can ping me in the [main unix.sx chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux). That is probably the best place to discuss this. Note that as mentioned in that answer, that patch may or may not apply cleanly to newer versions of gcc 4.9.